# google analytics filter's configuration is incorrect or data too small

Tags: google-analytics

I added a simple filter to a GA view that is supposed to only show my production traffic.

```
FilterType: predefined
Included Only
traffic to hostname
that are equal to
Hostname: mydomain.com
```

...then I click "Verify this filter" and google shows this error:

"This filter would not have changed your data. Either the filter configuration is incorrect, or the set of sampled data is too small."

We're small now, so only 90 sessions are showing. Is that "too small"?  If not, how would things be misconfigured?

Comment: For that particular warning, I wouldn't put too much stock into it. You can wait a day to see if the data in your reports reflects that the filter is working.

Comment: Are filters processed only once a day?  i.e. I shouldn't expect immediate results?

Comment: No, you won't see immediate results. You can try to check Real-Time reports under the Content section, but normally for the standard reports, it takes up to 24 hours for data to be processed.